# T-SQL Pivot - sort of

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Hopefully somebody can help me out here.
I have a table with data like this:

```
Form  Section  Data1  Data2  Data3  Data4
-----------------------------------------
1001  0000001  Data_  Null_  Null_  Null_
1001  0000002  Null_  Data_  Null_  Null_
1001  0000003  Null_  Null_  Data_  Null_
1001  0000004  Null_  Null_  Null_  Data_
1002  0000001  Data_  Null_  Null_  Null_
1002  0000002  Null_  Data_  Null_  Null_
1002  0000003  Null_  Null_  Data_  Null_
1002  0000004  Null_  Null_  Null_  Data_
```

I would like to present it in a table like so:

```
Form  Data1  Data2  Data3  Data4
--------------------------------
1001  Data_  Data_  Data_  Data_
1002  Data_  Data_  Data_  Data_
```

I'm sure this is relatively simple, but I have gone round and round looking at this and now with each attempt I just end up returning a list identical to what I started with! Which has pretty much fried my brain!
Any help would be much appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: Looks like you can throw an aggregate function around each `Data` column (`max`/`min`) and group by the `Form` column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need is a `conditional aggregate`. Considering those are not `DB NULL's`

```
SELECT Form,
       Max(CASE
             WHEN Data1 = 'Data_' THEN Data1
           END),
       Max(CASE
             WHEN Data2 = 'Data_' THEN Data2
           END),
       Max(CASE
             WHEN Data3 = 'Data_' THEN Data3
           END),
       Max(CASE
             WHEN Data4 = 'Data_' THEN Data4
           END)
FROM   <tablename>
GROUP  BY form
```

or if you have only these sets of data (ie) only `NULL_` and `Data_` then try this.

```
select Form ,Min(Data1),Min(Data2),Min(Data3),Min(Data4)
FROM   <tablename>
GROUP  BY form
```

**[SQL FIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f5c0b/2)**